# Three side-by-side tables

Tags: tables

I am using this LaTeX code to generate three tables side by side. However, it showing errors and not giving satisfactory result. Can anyone please help me to short out the problem.

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\makebox[0pt][c]{\parbox{1.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.265\hsize}\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c |c | }
\multicolumn{3}{c}
\hline
{$q=1/10$} \\
\hline
T & $r_h$ & $\omega$ \\ 
\hline
0.233 & 0.135 & 2.38486-0.34667I  \\ 
0.256 & 0.140 & 2.38092-0.35837I \\
0.273 & 0.145 & 2.38049-0.35982I \\ 
0.278 & 0.146 & 2.38007-0.36130I \\ 
0.281 & 0.147 & 2.37964-0.36282I \\ 
\hline
0.284 & 0.761 & 2.54150-2.03209I \\
0.285 & 0.765 & 2.54515-2.04292I \\
0.289 & 0.800 & 2.57799-2.13761I \\
0.302 & 0.900 & 2.67987-2.40712I \\
0.312 & 1.000 & 2.79214-2.67552I \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.265\hsize}\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | }
\multicolumn{3}{c}
\hline
{$q=1/9$} \\
\hline
T & $r_h$ & $\omega$ \\
\hline
0.227 & 0.150 & 2.34385-0.41094I  \\ 
0.245 & 0.155 & 2.34215-0.41723I \\
0.260 & 0.160 & 2.34056-0.42416I \\ 
0.271 & 0.165 & 2.33908-0.43175I \\ 
0.276 & 0.167 & 2.33852-0.43497I \\ 
\hline
0.280 & 0.720 & 2.50248-1.92299I \\
0.283 & 0.750 & 2.52893-2.00424I \\
0.286 & 0.780 & 2.55660-2.08533I \\
0.289 & 0.800 & 2.57568-2.13931I \\
0.302 & 0.900 & 2.67807-2.40842I \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.265\hsize}\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c |}
\multicolumn{3}{c}
\hline
{$q=1/8$} \\
\hline
T & $r_h$ & $\omega$ \\ 
\hline
0.246 & 0.180 & 2.29733-0.50611I  \\ 
0.255 & 0.185 & 2.29654-0.51364I \\
0.263 & 0.190 & 2.29589-0.52172I \\ 
0.269 & 0.195 & 2.29534-0.53033I \\ 
0.273 & 0.199 & 2.29496-0.53758I \\ 
\hline
0.275 & 0.675 & 2.46067-1.80426I \\
0.277 & 0.700 & 2.48131-1.87194I \\
0.288 & 0.800 & 2.57245-2.14170I \\
0.302 & 0.900 & 2.67555-2.41027I \\
0.317 & 1.000 & 2.78870-2.67796I \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
}}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that a `\hline` command within the argument of  `\multicolumn` as in  `\multicolumn{3}{c}\hline{$q=1/10$}` do not work. Just remove that `\hline` in each table and it should work.

On the other hand, consider remove the superfluous onion layers (`\makebox`, `\parbox,` and `minipages`) leaving this simple structure, that should work also:

```
\begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular} \hfill
\begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular} \hfill
\begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular}
```

If that do not fit in the page, is time to decrease the font size, or time of use a landscape page, may be with other margins, or re-design the table (Is it really useful to show 5 digits in a number near 2?) but *not of exceed the margins*. On the other hand ...please, please, avoid vertical lines and use the `booktabs` package to have better horizontal lines and vertical spacing. For example:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\multicolumn{3}{c}
{$q=1/10$} \\
\toprule
T & $r_h$ & $\omega$ \\ 
\midrule
0.233 & 0.135 & 2.38486-0.34667I  \\ 
0.256 & 0.140 & 2.38092-0.35837I \\
0.273 & 0.145 & 2.38049-0.35982I \\ 
0.278 & 0.146 & 2.38007-0.36130I \\ 
0.281 & 0.147 & 2.37964-0.36282I \\ 
\midrule
0.284 & 0.761 & 2.54150-2.03209I \\
0.285 & 0.765 & 2.54515-2.04292I \\
0.289 & 0.800 & 2.57799-2.13761I \\
0.302 & 0.900 & 2.67987-2.40712I \\
0.312 & 1.000 & 2.79214-2.67552I \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\multicolumn{3}{c}
{$q=1/9$} \\
\toprule
T & $r_h$ & $\omega$ \\
\midrule
0.227 & 0.150 & 2.34385-0.41094I  \\ 
0.245 & 0.155 & 2.34215-0.41723I \\
0.260 & 0.160 & 2.34056-0.42416I \\ 
0.271 & 0.165 & 2.33908-0.43175I \\ 
0.276 & 0.167 & 2.33852-0.43497I \\ 
\midrule
0.280 & 0.720 & 2.50248-1.92299I \\
0.283 & 0.750 & 2.52893-2.00424I \\
0.286 & 0.780 & 2.55660-2.08533I \\
0.289 & 0.800 & 2.57568-2.13931I \\
0.302 & 0.900 & 2.67807-2.40842I \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\multicolumn{3}{c}
{$q=1/8$} \\
\toprule
T & $r_h$ & $\omega$ \\ 
\midrule
0.246 & 0.180 & 2.29733-0.50611I  \\ 
0.255 & 0.185 & 2.29654-0.51364I \\
0.263 & 0.190 & 2.29589-0.52172I \\ 
0.269 & 0.195 & 2.29534-0.53033I \\ 
0.273 & 0.199 & 2.29496-0.53758I \\ 
\midrule
0.275 & 0.675 & 2.46067-1.80426I \\
0.277 & 0.700 & 2.48131-1.87194I \\
0.288 & 0.800 & 2.57245-2.14170I \\
0.302 & 0.900 & 2.67555-2.41027I \\
0.317 & 1.000 & 2.78870-2.67796I \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Fran....Thank you very much for your help. Appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions:

- No need for the `\makebox`, `\parbox` and `minipage` wrappers. Just provide three `tabular` environments, separated by `\hfill`.
- Actually, since all of the material in the tables is math-y, it's better to use `array` environments instead of `tabular` environments. For instance, you'll get typographic "minus" signs instead of typographic "dash" signs in the third column of each table.
- Try to go for an "open" look by (a) getting rid of all vertical lines and (b) using the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package instead of `\hline`.
- By reducing the values of `\arraycolsep` (the parameter that governs the amount of intercolumn whitespace) and `\medmuskip` (the parameter that governs the whitespace around the "minus" signs), you needn't reduce the font size in order to make the three tables fit side by side.

(The horizontal line at the top of the following screenshot is there just to illustrate the width of the text block.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,a4paper]{geometry} % set page parameters
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\hrule % just to illustrate width of text block

\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\arraycolsep{4pt} % default: 5pt
\medmuskip=3mu              % default: 4mu
$ % start math mode
\begin{array}{@{} ccc  @{}}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{q=1/10}\\
\toprule
T & r_h & \omega \\ 
\midrule
0.233 & 0.135 & 2.38486-0.34667I  \\ 
0.256 & 0.140 & 2.38092-0.35837I \\
0.273 & 0.145 & 2.38049-0.35982I \\ 
0.278 & 0.146 & 2.38007-0.36130I \\ 
0.281 & 0.147 & 2.37964-0.36282I \\ 
\addlinespace
0.284 & 0.761 & 2.54150-2.03209I \\
0.285 & 0.765 & 2.54515-2.04292I \\
0.289 & 0.800 & 2.57799-2.13761I \\
0.302 & 0.900 & 2.67987-2.40712I \\
0.312 & 1.000 & 2.79214-2.67552I \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\hfill
\begin{array}{@{} ccc @{}}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{q=1/9}\\
\toprule
T & r_h & \omega \\
\midrule
0.227 & 0.150 & 2.34385-0.41094I  \\ 
0.245 & 0.155 & 2.34215-0.41723I \\
0.260 & 0.160 & 2.34056-0.42416I \\ 
0.271 & 0.165 & 2.33908-0.43175I \\ 
0.276 & 0.167 & 2.33852-0.43497I \\ 
\addlinespace
0.280 & 0.720 & 2.50248-1.92299I \\
0.283 & 0.750 & 2.52893-2.00424I \\
0.286 & 0.780 & 2.55660-2.08533I \\
0.289 & 0.800 & 2.57568-2.13931I \\
0.302 & 0.900 & 2.67807-2.40842I \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\hfill
\begin{array}{@{} ccc @{}}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{q=1/8}\\
\toprule
T & r_h & \omega \\ 
\midrule
0.246 & 0.180 & 2.29733-0.50611I  \\ 
0.255 & 0.185 & 2.29654-0.51364I \\
0.263 & 0.190 & 2.29589-0.52172I \\ 
0.269 & 0.195 & 2.29534-0.53033I \\ 
0.273 & 0.199 & 2.29496-0.53758I \\ 
\addlinespace
0.275 & 0.675 & 2.46067-1.80426I \\
0.277 & 0.700 & 2.48131-1.87194I \\
0.288 & 0.800 & 2.57245-2.14170I \\
0.302 & 0.900 & 2.67555-2.41027I \\
0.317 & 1.000 & 2.78870-2.67796I \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
$ % end math mode
\end{table}
\end{document}
```